# about selenium, not knowing what errors are

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Here's my code and the error Python provides.
I'm a beginner using Python 3.6. Can anyone helps find out what's wrong? Many thanks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf-8

from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe')
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.bing.com/')
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\cxy61.com - html\python spider\001 selenium import.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe')
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 229, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 58.0.3029.0
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

Comment: It looks like your Chrome version is not up to date...

Comment: As @CoryMadden mentioned your chrome is old. The error message explicitly says `Chrome version must be >= 58.0.3029.0`.

Comment: thank you both for your help. but after update chrome, problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take care of a couple of things as follows:

1. As you are using `chromedriver v2.31` the error clearly states **`Chrome version must be >= 58.0.3029.0`**. So you need to bump up your Google Chrome version to v58.0 or above.
2. If you want to specify the absolute path of the `chromedriver` within single quotes `'...'` then you have to provide single forward slashes `\` only.
3. If you are assigning the webdriver instance to the `driver`, you have to use the `driver` instance only to open any `url`
4. Here is your own code with the above mentioned changes:

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver

   driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
   driver.get('http://www.bing.com/')
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help... but it does not work... I am still trying to figure this out.

Comment: @yumoliuxiang Can you update the question with your current code & error stack trace?